# highcharts-more + requirejs, Highcharts undefined

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs

I have following requirejs config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    shim: {
        ...
        highcharts: {
            deps: ['highcharts-more'],
            exports: 'Highcharts'
        }
        ...
    },
    paths: {
        ...
        'highcharts': 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts',
        'highcharts-more': 'http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more'
        ...
    }    
});
```

Then in my view:

```
define([
...
'highcharts',
...
], function (Highcharts) {
    // The speed gauge
    // Example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid
    $('#container-speed').highcharts(...);
});
```

In console i have: 
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined 
in highcharts-more.js

Any correct way how to load Highcharts-more.js with RequireJS?

Comment: See similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672872/preserving-jquery-dependency-for-highcharts-with-requirejs-optimizer

Comment: Highcharts error #17,
because Hicharts-more not loading in that way.

Comment: Strange, because [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wAM3h/) from there works properly, without any error.

Comment: That example doesn't using higcharts-more.js. More library needed for Gauge type of charts. Problem is highcharts-more doesn't works with AMD properly, since i have my Hicharts object in window.

Comment: You are right, sorry for my fault. I fixed example like here: http://jsfiddle.net/wAM3h/48/

Comment: Example doesn't works.

Comment: Which browser do you use, because for me chart is printed...(Chrome)

Comment: Strange, Chrome too.

Comment: I don't know why, but after couple of reloads it start working. I will try your solution in my app. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need configure something in requirejs, honesly Im not requirejs expert.

Comment: Works! Thank you, master! .)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dependencies are reversed. `highcharts-more` depends on highcharts being loaded. Hence, make sure `highcharts` is loaded as dependency(`deps`) in `deps` array:

```
highcharts-more: {
    deps: ['highcharts'],
    exports: 'Highcharts'
}
```

Comment: Error: Load timeout for modules: highcharts,highcharts-more